# Magento Product Page Custom Tabs Location

Tags: php, xml, magento

I'm using Ultratabs extension by NWDTHEMES, and what I figured from the xml file is that it removes the default tabs by Magento and placed it in a block called content.

EDIT: I would like to move the current product tabs from below everything else to just right under the add-to-wishlist block. like http://fyringe.com/index.php/whats-new-13/farlap-shirt-ruby.html

I've been tweaking with the XML as instructed by extension author but with no success. Could someone help me please?

The contents of the XML File:

```
<ultratabs_catalog_product_view>
    <remove name="product.info.tabs" />
    <reference name="product.info">
        <action method="unsetChild"><name>description</name></action>
        <action method="unsetChild"><name>additional</name></action>
        <action method="unsetChild"><name>upsell_products</name></action>
        <action method="unsetChild"><name>reviews</name></action>
        <action method="unsetChild"><name>related_products</name></action>
        <action method="unsetChild"><name>product_tag_list</name></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="right">
        <action method="unsetChild"><name>catalog.product.related</name></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="product.info.additional">
        <action method="unsetChild"><name>product_tag_list</name></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="ultratabs/ultratabs" name="product.info.ultratabs" as="ultratabs" after="-">
            <action method="setTemplate" ifconfig="ultratabs_options/general/enabled"><template>nwdthemes/ultratabs/tabs.phtml</template></action>
            <action method="addTab" translate="title" module="catalog" ifconfig="ultratabs_options/general/description_enabled">
                <alias>description</alias>
                <title>Description</title>
                <block>catalog/product_view_description</block>
                <template>catalog/product/view/description.phtml</template>
            </action>
            <action method="addTab" translate="title" module="catalog" ifconfig="ultratabs_options/general/additional_enabled">
                <alias>additional</alias>
                <title>Additional Information</title>
                <block>catalog/product_view_attributes</block>
                <template>catalog/product/view/attributes.phtml</template>
            </action>
            <action method="addTab" translate="title" module="catalog" ifconfig="ultratabs_options/general/upsell_enabled">
                <alias>upsell</alias>
                <title>We Also Recommend</title>
                <block>catalog/product_list_upsell</block>
                <template>catalog/product/list/upsell.phtml</template>
            </action>
            <action method="addTab" translate="title" module="catalog" ifconfig="ultratabs_options/general/related_enabled">
                <alias>related</alias>
                <title>Related Products</title>
                <block>catalog/product_list_related</block>
                <template>nwdthemes/ultratabs/related_tab.phtml</template>
            </action>
            <action method="addTab" translate="title" module="tag" ifconfig="ultratabs_options/general/tags_enabled">
                <alias>tags</alias>
                <title>Tags</title>
                <block>tag/product_list</block>
                <template>tag/list.phtml</template>
            </action>
            <action method="addTab" translate="title" module="catalog" ifconfig="ultratabs_options/general/review_enabled">
                <alias>review</alias>
                <title>Reviews</title>
                <block>review/product_view_list</block>
                <template>nwdthemes/ultratabs/review_tab.phtml</template>
            </action>
            <block type="review/form" name="product.review.form" as="review_form" />
        </block>
    </reference>
</ultratabs_catalog_product_view>
```

Any help would be appreciated!! Thanks!!

Comment: Not too clear. You mention you want to re-adjust block order. In which order are the blocks displaying incorrectly now and in which order do you want them to display in?

Comment: The [link provided](http://fyringe.com/index.php/whats-new-13/farlap-shirt-ruby.html) is dead.

Comment: This is no the support site of NWDThemes here. This is Stackoverflow, a Q&A site about *general* programming. Please direct your support questions to the software vendor and checkout their support options. Please make yourself comfortable with what is considered [on-topic on Stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). (The third-party software you ask about does not allow you to post the shortest example possible as you haven't licensed their code to be posted on Stackoverflow)

Comment: Ah yes, @hakre I know. But I just came here desperately looking for help on this.

Comment: The link is http://www.fyringe.com/index.php/whats-new-13/farlap-shirt-ruby.html

Comment: I tried to change the following line: <reference name="content"> to <reference name="product.info"> and did a <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product.info.ultratabs') ?> too, but still not working.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check this line

```
 <action method="unsetChild"><name>description</name></action>
        <action method="unsetChild"><name>additional</name></action>
        <action method="unsetChild"><name>upsell_products</name></action>
        <action method="unsetChild"><name>reviews</name></action>
        <action method="unsetChild"><name>related_products</name>/action>
        <action method="unsetChild"><name>product_tag_list</name>/action>
```

You need to change above lines with following

```
 <action method="setChild"><name>description</name></action>
    <action method="setChild"><name>additional</name></action>
    <action method="setChild"><name>upsell_products</name></action>
    <action method="setChild"><name>reviews</name></action>
    <action method="setChild"><name>related_products</name></action>
    <action method="setChild"><name>product_tag_list</name></action>
```

check after refresh cache